# How to perform query on two unrelated tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a `table A` with `Id` and `Geometry`

[image]

And `Temporary table B`

[image]

Each Geometry of `Temporary table B` has intersecting geometry in `Table A`. I want to find the intersecting geometry and make a union of the geometry. The final table should be id of `Table A` which is having intersection and the union of geometry. If there are more than 1 intersecting geometry then pick any one.

[image]

I can not perform join here as there is no common column between these tables so don't know how to get the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the demo, I took types `intrange` for simulating the types `geometry`. Ranges are close enough to get the same query:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=847ceb1a64aebde35fcebb6a618e1620)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.id)       -- 3
    a.id,
    a.geom + b.geom             -- 2
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.geom && b.geom      -- 1
```

1. Join condition should be the check for intersection. For ranges it is `&&` operator, in your case it should be `st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)`
2. Union both geometries. Here it is done using the `+` operator, in your case it should be `st_union(a.geom, b.geom)`
3. `DISTINCT ON(b.id)` ensures that there's only one record per `b.id`

So, your final query should look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.id)                    -- 3
    a.id,
    st_union(a.geom, b.geom)                 -- 2
FROM a
JOIN b ON st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)      -- 1
```

Comment: By what OP asks, values of a.id are not necessarily distinct. OP says that if a geometry from temp_table_B intersects with a geometry from table_A, a single a.id should be kept. But what if a geometry from table_A intersects with multiple geometries of temp_table_B?

Comment: You are right. It must be DISTINCT ON (b.id)

Comment: @S-Man but b doesn't have column id.

Comment: You should always have an identifier in your table! However, you can easily generate one, using the row_number() window function: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a5508ad35c21421062ec417ce73b2565

Comment: @S-Man that's a good point. Unfortunately when I use row_number in combination with st_dump it generates the same id for all. SELECT row_number() OVER () as id,(st_dump(ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-29 -27,-30 -29.7,-36 -31,-45 -33),(-45 -33,-46 -32))'))).geom

Comment: You can do this in a subquery: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22f9eadd67961a0c25d9af7041481239

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I'd appreciate if you could upvote as well. Please don't forget to upvote ALL answers that could help in any way. This honors the time and effort, the replier invested into your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following SQL would work:

```
SELECT a.id, ST_UNION(a.geometry, b.geometry) 
FROM table_A as a, temp_table_B as b 
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
```

You can group the results to handle multiple intersections.

Comment: Doesn't fit the last requirement. It returns two unions if there are any.

Comment: It is not clear by the OP how to handle multiple intersections. What if a geometry from table_A intersects with multiple geometries from temp_table_B? OP only states what to happen in the opposite case (if geometry from temp_table_B intersects with muliple geometries from table_A, keep a single id from table_A). Therefore, I posted the main logic, OP can edit it according to his needs.

Answer (score -1):

If a dataset is not so big and geometry values follow the same pattern as you've shown above, you could look at this solution

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id
          , 'LineAB' AS geometry
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
         , 'LineDE'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
         , 'LineFG'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4
         , 'LineXY' )
         
, temp_b AS (
    SELECT 'LineBC' AS geometry
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LineCD'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LineEF' )
    
, a_last AS (
    SELECT a.id
         , a.geometry
         , RIGHT(a.geometry, 1) AS a_key            -- get the last symbol for further join with temp_b
      FROM a )
, a_nlast AS (
    SELECT a.id
         , a.geometry
         , SUBSTRING(a.geometry, 5, 1) AS a_key
      FROM a )
, b_nlast AS (
    SELECT temp_b.geometry
         , SUBSTRING(temp_b.geometry, 5, 1) AS b_key        -- get one symbol before the last symbol for further join with a table
      FROM temp_b )
, b_last AS (
    SELECT temp_b.geometry
         , RIGHT(temp_b.geometry, 1) AS b_key
      FROM temp_b )
-- try all possible combinations of last and not last sybols from both tables
SELECT a_last.id
     , CONCAT('Union (', SUBSTRING(a_last.geometry, 5, 2), '+', SUBSTRING(b_nlast.geometry, 5, 2), ')') 
  FROM a_last JOIN b_nlast ON a_last.a_key = b_nlast.b_key
UNION ALL 
SELECT a_last.id
     , CONCAT('Union (', SUBSTRING(a_last.geometry, 5, 2), '+', SUBSTRING(b_last.geometry, 5, 2), ')') 
  FROM a_last JOIN b_last ON a_last.a_key = b_last.b_key
UNION ALL
SELECT a_nlast.id
     , CONCAT('Union (', SUBSTRING(a_nlast.geometry, 5, 2), '+', SUBSTRING(b_last.geometry, 5, 2), ')') 
  FROM a_nlast JOIN b_last ON a_nlast.a_key = b_last.b_key
UNION ALL
SELECT a_nlast.id
     , CONCAT('Union (', SUBSTRING(a_nlast.geometry, 5, 2), '+', SUBSTRING(b_nlast.geometry, 5, 2), ')') 
  FROM a_nlast JOIN b_nlast ON a_nlast.a_key = b_nlast.b_key;
```

This solution takes certain symbols from the given pattern and tries different combinations to form the list of all possible combinations.

The question is about ids. It is said that it should take id from a table, but if you want it to be unique it would be better to create a separate table, where you could put the resulting combinations with their own unique ids.